# How to present a nested dictionary as a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing, format

I have the following dictionary:

[image: Dictionary]

I would like to print these dictionaries out so they appear in an easy to read table like this **without using pandas**:

[image: Output should look like this]

What I have so far:

[image: Current code]

I am able to get the table headers to print but I am having trouble mapping up the other columns.

Here is the dictionary as text to copy:

```
{'ffa': {'cope1': 0.6525,
         'cope2': 0.4146,
         'cope3': 0.5896,
         'cope4': 0.1521,
         'cope5': 0.5317},
 'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001,
             'cope2': -0.150985,
             'cope3': -0.162005,
             'cope4': -0.130845,
             'cope5': -0.126411},
 'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836,
         'cope2': 0.9444,
         'cope3': 0.300482,
         'cope4': 1.12435,
         'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}
```

Comment: Does the 'Mean' column indicate mean of all 'cope1'? Could you also paste the dictionary as text instead of image, so others can replicate it easily?

Comment: I have added the dictionary. I have already calculated the means before adding them to the dictionary so the table should just display the value for FFA - Cope1 and so on

Comment: So for each list in the dictionary will have results for Cope1 - 5 printed in the mean column just use them as they are and the name for each list should be in the ROI column as shown

Comment: edit: * without using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1 - pandas

I would suggest using a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe for this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ffa': {'cope1': 0.6525, 'cope2': 0.4146, 'cope3': 0.5896, 'cope4': 0.1521, 'cope5': 0.5317}, 'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001, 'cope2': -0.150985, 'cope3': -0.162005, 'cope4': -0.130845, 'cope5': -0.126411}, 'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836, 'cope2': 0.9444, 'cope3': 0.300482, 'cope4': 1.12435, 'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}
data = [(k,*x)  for k, v in d.items() for x in v.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ROI', 'COPE', 'MEAN'])
```

Gives:

```
>>> df
        ROI   COPE      MEAN
0       ffa  cope1  0.652500
1       ffa  cope2  0.414600
2       ffa  cope3  0.589600
3       ffa  cope4  0.152100
4       ffa  cope5  0.531700
5   lingual  cope1 -0.088651
6   lingual  cope2 -0.150985
7   lingual  cope3 -0.162005
8   lingual  cope4 -0.130845
9   lingual  cope5 -0.126411
10      ppa  cope1  0.748360
11      ppa  cope2  0.944400
12      ppa  cope3  0.300482
13      ppa  cope4  1.124350
14      ppa  cope5  0.833220
```

### Option 2 - just print the table

To just print without using pandas:

```
d = {'ffa': {'cope1': 0.6525, 'cope2': 0.4146, 'cope3': 0.5896, 'cope4': 0.1521, 'cope5': 0.5317}, 'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001, 'cope2': -0.150985, 'cope3': -0.162005, 'cope4': -0.130845, 'cope5': -0.126411}, 'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836, 'cope2': 0.9444, 'cope3': 0.300482, 'cope4': 1.12435, 'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}
data = [(k,*x)  for k, v in d.items() for x in v.items()]
print ("ROI            COPE        MEAN")
for l in data:
        print ("{:<14}{:<11}{}".format(l[0],l[1],l[2]))
```

Gives:

```
ROI            COPE        MEAN
ffa           cope1      0.6525
ffa           cope2      0.4146
ffa           cope3      0.5896
ffa           cope4      0.1521
ffa           cope5      0.5317
lingual       cope1      -0.08865060000000001
lingual       cope2      -0.150985
lingual       cope3      -0.162005
lingual       cope4      -0.130845
lingual       cope5      -0.126411
ppa           cope1      0.74836
ppa           cope2      0.9444
ppa           cope3      0.300482
ppa           cope4      1.12435
ppa           cope5      0.8332200000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
data = {'ffa': {'cope1': 0.6525, 'cope2': 0.4146, 'cope3': 0.5896, 'cope4': 0.1521, 'cope5': 0.5317},
        'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001, 'cope2': -0.150985, 'cope3': -0.162005, 'cope4': -0.130845, 'cope5': -0.126411},
        'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836, 'cope2': 0.9444, 'cope3': 0.300482, 'cope4': 1.12435, 'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}

def items1(data):
    for roi, v in data.items():
        for cope, mean in v.items():
            yield (roi, cope, mean)

def items2(data):
    return (
        (roi, cope, mean)
            for roi, v in data.items()
                for cope, mean in v.items()
    )

def pretty_print(data_items, formatter='{:<8} {:<15} {:<10}'.format):
    print(formatter('ROI', 'COPE', 'MEAN'))
    for itm in data_items:
        print(formatter(*itm))

assert list(items1(data)) == list(items2(data))

pretty_print(items2(data))
```

Result:

```
ROI      COPE            MEAN      
ffa      cope1           0.6525    
ffa      cope2           0.4146    
ffa      cope3           0.5896    
ffa      cope4           0.1521    
ffa      cope5           0.5317    
lingual  cope1           -0.08865060000000001
lingual  cope2           -0.150985 
lingual  cope3           -0.162005 
lingual  cope4           -0.130845 
lingual  cope5           -0.126411 
ppa      cope1           0.74836   
ppa      cope2           0.9444    
ppa      cope3           0.300482  
ppa      cope4           1.12435   
ppa      cope5           0.8332200000000001
```